# How do I run an Eclipse Helios project right on my Android Phone?

Tags: android, eclipse-3.6

I have an HTC Desire and I cannot figure out how to run my eclipse keyboard on it. Can someone please help me? I don't want to run it on my Android Emulator because when you turn it landscape the keyboard doesn't show up. Neither does the one that comes with the emulator. HELP ME PLEASE!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you mean something like this:

you have a program in Eclipse. It doesn't work in the emulator, and you want to test it on a real device. How do I get it on a real device?

Then the answer would be: Build an APK, and send it (web, mail, usb, flash-card.. anything) to your phone, and install it while having the "non-market apks' checkbox enabled in the settings on your phone.

Making an apk is explained in the manual. You can go the whole way, and [sign your app](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html). Or you can skip that. Either way, it all starts with your project, right mouse -> android-tools ->export apk (or something similar;) )

Answer (score 1):

Attach your phone to your computer, probably through the USB cable. Then use that as the Device when you run the program, instead of the emulator. This will install the program on your phone.

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

Here is the setup help from Android.